# Serialize xml with different ElementName to same object with VB.net or C#

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I can receive a xml trace in differents languages like these examples:

```xml
<Persona>        
    <Nombre>Josep</Nombre>        
    <Edad>26</Edad>        
</Persona>

<Person>  
    <Name>Josep</Name>  
    <Age>26</Age>  
</Person>
```

And I need to serialize into the same object using VB.net or C#.

I declared the object like this:

```vb
Public Class Person     
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Nombre">  
    Public n_nombre As String  
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Edad")>  
    Public n_edad As String  
End Class
```

How I can declare it for admit its? Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use models which implement the same interface. The specific model can specify the xml element name corresponding to the language:

```vb
<XmlRoot("Persona")> _
Public Class Person_Es
    Implements IXMLPerson
    <XmlElement("Edad")> _
    Public Property Age As Long Implements IXMLPerson.Age
    <XmlElement("Nombre")> _
    Public Property Name As String Implements IXMLPerson.Name
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

<XmlRoot("Person")> _
Public Class Person_En
    Implements IXMLPerson
    <XmlElement("Age")> _
    Public Property Age As Long Implements IXMLPerson.Age
    <XmlElement("Name")> _
    Public Property Name As String Implements IXMLPerson.Name
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Interface IXMLPerson
    Property Name As String
    Property Age As Long
End Interface
```

And to load the xml into memory, only the correct language will serialize, so I used nested `Try`. If you have many languages, you would want to architect it a little better as to reduce and reuse code. This works for english and spanish:

```vb
Dim filename As String = "<your file name here>"
Dim myPerson As IXMLPerson = Nothing
Try
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Person_Es))
    Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
        myPerson = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Person_Es)
    End Using
Catch ex1 As Exception
    Try
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Person_En))
        Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
            myPerson = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Person_En)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Try
```